# Wordpress permalink and HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, http, https, permalinks, cloudflare

I installed HTTPS on my website in WordPress . I use CloudFlare for it and I made changes to the URL in WordPress administration and the CloudFlare plugins etc.

[screenshot of home page modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuxvb.jpg)

My concern is the following I have HTTPS in my WordPress general settings . I have HTTPS in the permalinks confirmation page.

Only once editing a page or a project under the title permiliens the portfolio is in HTTP ...

I do not understand why it does not go into HTTPS ( for doing so on other sites I do not remember such a problem).

Can you help me?

Comment: I find the solution with this page :

http://ithemes.com/codex/page/Fix_Non-SSL_Elements_on_SSL_Page

And the plugin : Fix SSL/Non-SSL Links

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that your site is only opening up with https and not with http and https.

In the WP general settings wordpress and site name should start with https

Then logout and then login back to wordpress admin. Post that your permalinks should start displaying as https. Also you need to change the internal links to https manually.

Let me know if that fixed the issue. I had similar problems with my site, for which i moved to https just yesterday. Also let me know if you did anything extra for your site.